# Realm.asyncOpen doesn't open realm

Tags: swift, realm

I can't open a realm with Realm.asyncOpen.

```
    guard let user = userName.text else { return }
    guard let password = password.text else { return }
    let credentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: user, password: password)
    let syncURL = URL(string: "\(Constants.REALM_URL)/~/Pictu")!

    SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: Constants.AUTH_URL) { user, error in

        if let error = error {
            print("User Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if let user = user {
            let realmConfig = user.configuration(realmURL: syncURL)
            Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: realmConfig) { realm, error in
                if let realm = realm {
                    print("Realm Open")
                    self.realm = realm
                } else if let error = error {
                    print("Realm Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I got the user but not the realm.
The error message is Operation canceled.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.

In my case it needs to specify fullSynchronizacion as true in configuration.

```
let config = user.configuration(realmURL: syncURL, fullSynchronization: true)
```